# How to create a user who can only access one directory?

Tags: server, phpmyadmin, user-management

I'm running Ubuntu Server 12.04. I was wondering how I can set up a user to only access one directory.  For example, I want to create a user 'brad' and want him to only have access to `/var/www/brad`. There, he can add and edit files as he pleases.  Also, how could I give him access to phpmyadmin to create db's?

Comment: How does brad connect to the machine? Will he have physical access? SSH? FTP?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  If he literally only has access to one directory he won't be able to do much.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo adduser brad
sudo chown brad:brad /var/www/brad
```

`man adduser` and `man chown` for more information and advanced options. Notice the `chown` above will only give ownership of the directory, use `-R` flag to do it recursively. Also notice no other user except brad will have ownership of said directory. You might need to change permissions for other users with `chmod`. Read about file permissions [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-linux-file-permissions-work/).

You can also do:

`sudo chown me:brad /var/www/brad`

So you are the owner and brad is the group which has access to it (brad is the only member of said group). Or the other way around:

`sudo chown brad:my_group /var/www/brad`

Notice `www-data` might need access to said folder (and sub-directories and files) for the webserver to function properly.

> Also how could I give him access to phpmyadmin to create db's?

You should configure that in your webserver / through phpmyadmin. If permission is denied for some reason, just adjust it with `chown` or `chmod`.

Comment: -1: This will simply give brad access to `/var/www/brad` it will not stop him from having access to other directories. For example, his $HOME will still be `/home/brad` and he will be able to happily access all system directories.

Comment: @terdon `umask` is 0022 on Debian-based systems. It doesn't matter how he creates the user, it'll always be able to read most folders, since that's the default behavior (755 for folders and 644 for files). However, created as mentioned, `brad` only belongs to the `brad` group and only has write permissions to the `brad` folder (and some others, such as `/tmp`, which also doesn't matter how he'd create the user, since it's 777 by default). If he doesn't want a dir at `/home` he just has to append `--no-create-home` to `adduser`, as specified in the man page I mentioned for advanced options.

Comment: Note that the OP mentioned "add and edit files". I took that as write permissions. If he doesn't want **read** permissions I guess he'd have to `chmod` most of the system and possibly break something or set `umask` to something else and re-install everything from scratch (and possibly break something in the process).

Comment: I know, that's why I posted a comment and not an answer :). It is actually possible and might be easy depending on how the user connects. We need more details from the OP but sandboxing a user account is possible. However, the approach you describe does not stop `brad` from having write access both to `/tmp` and to `/home/brad` which will be created automatically by `adduser`, it simply gives brad write access to `/var/www/brad` and does not restrict the user in any way.

Comment: This is overkill  Setup a vhost... dont point Brad to var/www point the vhost  to /home/brad/public_html/<whatever>, then chown of /var/www to apache, point your hosts file to your vhost